# WSO2 EMM 2.2.0 : the file "app conf.json" and "config.json"

Tags: wso2-iot

Sorry for my English because I use Google Translate. My name is Tof and am French.

I am trying to install WSO2 EMM 2.2.0 Alpha

What is the difference between the file "app-conf.json" and "config.json"

On the document online, you are asked to change the config.json including its external IP address. [WSO2EMM 2.2.0 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/Android+Device#AndroidDevice-Configuringtheemailclient)

But if you look at the file more ready, we see that the IP address is provided by an environment variable

example:

```
    "generalConfig" : {
    "host" : "%http.ip%",
    "companyName" : "WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager",
    "browserTitle" : "WSO2 EMM",
    "copyrightText" : "\u00A9 %date-year%, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved."
},
```

If I edit the file that is in the same directory: **app-conf.json** I contaste there this information:

```
    "generalConfig" : {
    "host" : "https://localhost:9443",
```

This is the same for 2 .json file that is in the /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/ emm-web-agent/app/conf and in the /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/app/conf

My question :
Documentation request to change the config.json but we can see that app conf.json should be modified. Your opinion ?

What differences there are between the app and the file conf.json config.json file?

Thank you for your help

Tof

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between the file "app-conf.json" and "config.json"?

app-conf.json which contains all the configurations which are used for /emm web application. Correct location of this should be **repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/app/conf**. As you pointed out another app-conf.json can be found in here: **/repository/deployment/server/ jaggeryapps/emm-web-agent/app/conf** which was added mistakenly and this will be removed in the next release. 
On the other hand config.json which contains configurations information which specific for a given web application. As an example, config.json which is included in the emm-web-agent web application is used getting its configuration information.Because of that, you are required to change config.json as mentioned in the documentation. It was mentioned to change the IP address because if you are to configure EMM cluster then this is the URL which is used to download device agent from device side. Hope this answered to your question.

Comment: Hi Gprathap, Thank for your reply